# Repair syntax error at or near "INNER" while using update?

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, syntax-error, inner-join

I have this error when i try to do an update with a inner:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INNER"
LINE 1: UPDATE sale_order AS so SET state='progress' INNER JOIN sale...
                                                     ^
```

the syntax is :

```
UPDATE sale_order AS so 
SET so.state='progress' 
INNER JOIN sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi ON so.id= soi.order_id 
INNER JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON soi.invoice_id=ai.id
WHERE so.state='done' AND ai.state !='paid';
```

the schema of the table is  :

- `sale_order : id | state`
- `sale_order_invoice_rel : id | order_id |invoice_id`
- `account_invoice : id | state`

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html

Comment: Sorry but this isn't useful my problem is on th join and the documention didn't help , instead thanks for the help

Comment: Why didn't the documentation help? Where does it say you can write what you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

The postgres update syntax is:

- UPDATE target_table
- SET ...
- FROM other_table
- [ optional JOIN  ... ON ... ]
- WHERE ...

---

```
UPDATE sale_order AS so 
SET state = 'progress' 
FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id -- <<-- this line
JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON soi.invoice_id = ai.id
WHERE so.state = 'done' AND ai.state <> 'paid' -- <<-- this line
  ;
```

---

Updated (removed correlation name from `SET so.state = ...` -> `SET state =` ...)

UPDATE2 (oops!) 2015-02-12 (move the `ON ...` to the `WHERE ...` clause)

```
UPDATE sale_order AS so 
SET state = 'progress' 
FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi
JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON soi.invoice_id = ai.id
WHERE so.id = soi.order_id -- <<-- this line
AND so.state = 'done' AND ai.state <> 'paid'
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for you help but this didn't work too :
UPDATE sale_order AS so 
SET so.state = 'progress' 
FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id                  
JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON soi.invoice_id = ai.id
WHERE so.state = 'done' AND ai.state <> 'paid'
  ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
LINE 3: FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id

Comment: `SET so.state='progress' ` You should not use an alias/correlation name at the left side of the assignment --> `SET state='progress' `

Comment: UPDATE sale_order AS so 
    SET state = 'progress' 
    FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id
    JOIN account_invoice AS ai ON soi.invoice_id = ai.id
    WHERE so.state = 'done' AND ai.state <> 'paid'
      ;
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
    LINE 3: FROM sale_order_invoice_rel AS soi ON so.id = soi.order_id

Comment: Oops, I errord when converting your `JOIN` to a `FROM` .